# How can I run phpunit using shell_exec or exec command

Tags: php, shell, phpunit, exec, shell-exec

I have the following command:

```
php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

and when I attempt to run it inside the shell, I am using Git Bash, there are no problems. However I do have to run the same command using php commands shell_exec or exec and I am not able to do that. All other shell commands can be run using either shell_exec or exec except this one. Path is correct and so are the permissions and I have also attempted following combination

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/php phpunit
```

Comment: change permissions on that file. shell_exec runs as user apache, meaning that if file is not accessible, nor not executable by apache it will not work. Also make sure that you can do shell_execs by running shell_exec('whoami');

Comment: @Dimi The file is accessible and every other command that I run by either **exec** or **shell_exec**, including writing to the file in question will be executed except this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to bypass this problem by creating new Artisan command.